# How can I further destruct set of variables that all begin with parent class?

Tags: javascript

I have a set of destructured variables that all have the same parent class. Is there a way to remove 'hollow-gallery-01' from each and add that to the destructuring process?

```
 const [modal,ctrls,slides,close,images,arrows] =
            [
                document.querySelector('.hollow-gallery-01 .modal'),
                document.querySelectorAll('.hollow-gallery-01 .control'),
                document.querySelectorAll('.hollow-gallery-01 .slide'),
                document.querySelector('.hollow-gallery-01 .close'),
                document.querySelectorAll('.hollow-gallery-01 .img-wrap'),
                document.querySelectorAll('.hollow-gallery-01 .arrow')
            ]
```

Comment: What is purpose of destructuring here? Directly assign the variables like `const modal = document.querySelector(...), ctrls = document.querySelectorAll(...),` etc..?

Comment: I am just learning and exploring possibilities. I figure something like this may be useful on much larger projects in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
const [[modal], ctrls, slides, [close], images, arrows] = ["modal", "control", "slide", "close", "img-wrap", "arrow"].map(sel =>
    document.querySelectorAll(".hollow-gallery-01 ." + sel)
);
```

to reduce the repetition.

---

That said, a better and more efficent approach (as also suggested by the other answers) is to use the selectors on the parent element, not `document`:

```
const gallery = document.querySelector('.hollow-gallery-01');
const modal = gallery.querySelector('.modal'),
      ctrls  = gallery.querySelectorAll('.control'),
      slides = gallery.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
      close = gallery.querySelector('.close'),
      images = gallery.querySelectorAll('img-wrap'),
      arrows = gallery.querySelectorAll('arrow');
```

Comment: Thank you for the awesome explanation. I am just exploring possibilities and trying to find the most efficient way to do things.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for you. console.log and html is for demo purposes.

```js
 var parentobj = document.getElementsByClassName("hollow-gallery-01")[0];
 const [modal,ctrls,slides,close,images,arrows] =
            [
                parentobj.querySelector('.modal'),
                parentobj.querySelectorAll('.control'),
                parentobj.querySelectorAll('.slide'),
                parentobj.querySelector('.close'),
                parentobj.querySelectorAll('.img-wrap'),
                parentobj.querySelectorAll('.arrow')
            ];
            
            console.log(modal.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="hollow-gallery-01">
<div class="modal">test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear why you're using destructuring here rather than assigning the variables directly, but if you wanted to simplify the selectors you could get the parent class, and then use `querySelector` on that.

```
const parent = document.querySelector('.hollow-gallery-01');

const modal = parent.querySelector('.modal');
const controls = parent.querySelectorAll('.control');
```

etc.